# Can not use '$query' in slim 3 with Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, slim-3

I use slim 3 for microservice for that i install laravel eloquent and i write a laravel query like following

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

DB::enableQueryLog();

$faqs = DB::table('rental_faq')
    ->where('id', '!=', '')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('isActive', '=', 1)
            ->orWhere('isDelete', '=', 'no');
    })
    ->get();
```

then the problem is it shows a error like following

"
There was an error parsing JSON data
Unexpected token I in JSON at position 743
"

I want to perform and_where and or_where operation separated parenthesis

Comment: I think there is something you are not presenting us with.., just dd the result of $faqs and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $maincat=25;
 $subcat=30;

$faqs=DB::table('rental_faq')
         ->where('isActive',1)
         ->where('isDelete','no')
         ->where(function ($query) use($maincat,$subcat) {
                $query->where('main_category',$maincat)
                      ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,sub_category)',[$subcat]);

        })
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with MySQL "NOT" function like so:

```
$faqs = DB::table('rental_faq')
    ->where('id', '<>', '')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('isActive', 1)
            ->orWhere('isDelete', 'no');
    })
    ->get();
dd($faqs);
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hi,When i update  above query like this $active=1;
$delete='no';

$faqs = DB::table('rental_faq')
->where('id', '<>', '')
->where(function ($query) {
$query->where('isActive', $active)
->orWhere('isDelete', $delete);
})
->get();  then   didn't get result

Comment: what do you mean `didn't get result `, you get `null`? and also if you just hardcode the values of `$active` and `$delete` i query then do you get any results?

Comment: $faqs=DB::table('rental_faq')
->where('isActive',1)
->where('isDelete','no')
->where(function ($query) {
$query->where('main_category','=',$classified[0]->maincat)
->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,sub_category)',[$classified[0]->subcat]);

})
->get();   This my actual query  it didn't  work    in above code  i just show a samplw query.Dynamic varraibles inside function($query) is not working

Comment: OK, can you like tell me what are you getting inside `$faqs`? `null`? `[]`? what? or if you are getting any error?